# Angularjs ng-repeat-start /end and filter weird behaviour

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create Master Details in table 
here is the  [plnkr Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLMAxRghYNgh2eUBXCml?p=preview)

but as i start putting filter for the ng-repeat the dom rendering behaves weird

click the + button to expand row and the search the textbox

am i doing some thing wrong

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `ng-repeat-end` and `ng-if` do not play well together. If you place the `ng-if` in the `<p>` element, your example is working. Of course this has the (undesired?) effect of allways including the details row in the DOM, event though it will be hidden.

Comment: can you suggest better solution to handle this problem,as i want to have a row for details